# Tips for transitioning from Visual Basic to Xcode

Tags: vb.net, xcode

I've been programming in VB.net for a while now, and I finally got access to a mac to make ipod apps. What are some useful sites, videos, etc. that could help me get used to Objective C and the Xcode IDE? I've stumbled upon the samples on the apple dev site, but none of them really give good examples which I could learn the syntax of the language from.

Thanks for the help, Objective C is really a big change from VB.net!

Comment: I also know C#, which would probably help some...but vb.net is my main language.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some helpful starter references from the Apple site, first for Objective-C itself, then for the Cocoa frameworks.

[Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/index.html)

[Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html)

There are also "getting started" videos available from http://developer.apple.com/iphone (you have to register as a developer to get access, but that's free)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) if you like working with .Net.  As far as I'm aware, it only works with C#, but it will let you use the .NET api to program for the iPhone.   Might be worth looking into if you don't want to learn Objective C.

Comment: The goal is to use Objective C, and MonoTouch is quite expensive. I want to transition.